# Transition between two classes in React - React routing issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to do a very simple React slide in submenu and I don't get why it doesn't work. I am toggling classes with setting the state.

```
<div id="sideNavBar" className={this.props.sideBar}>
```

Css:

```
#sideNavBar {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #3B3B3B);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    min-height: 800px;
    width: 180px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#sideNavBar.SideBar {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#sideNavBar.SideBar_hidden {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

---------------------------------------------------------ADDITIONAL COMPONENT
App.js
.....

```
 class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          isBlog: false,
          isPhotography: false,
          isDesign: false,
          sideBar: 'SideBar_hidden'
        }
        this.selectPage = this.selectPage.bind(this);
      }

  selectPage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ((event.target.name)==='blog') {
    this.setState({sideBar: 'SideBar', isBlog: true, isPhotography: false, isDesign: false})
    }
    else if((event.target.name)==='photography') {
    this.setState({sideBar: 'SideBar', isBlog: false, isPhotography: true, isDesign: false})
    }
    else if ((event.target.name)==='design') {
    this.setState({sideBar: 'SideBar', isPhotography: false, isDesign: true})
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
        <Navigation selectPage={this.selectPage}/>
          <div className="content">
            <div className="body">
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={(routeProps) => (<div><SideBar sideBar={this.state.sideBar}/></div>)}/>
        </Switch>
            <Switch>
            <Route path='/blog' render={(routeProps) => (<div><SideBar sideBar={this.state.sideBar}/>
              <Blog /></div>)}/>
            </Switch>
            <Switch>
            <Route path='/photography' render={(routeProps) => (<div><SideBar sideBar={this.state.sideBar}/>
              <Photography/></div>)}/>
            </Switch>
            <Switch>
            <Route path='/design' render={(routeProps) => (<div><SideBar sideBar={this.state.sideBar}/>
              <Design/></div>)}/>
            </Switch>
            </div>
            <div className="footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

From "/" clicking any of the menu links (blog etc.) the sidebar menu just pops in. If I am at "/blog" route and refresh the page to set the state back to hidden and then click on the blog link it slides in. But if I am at /blog refresh the page to setthe state to hidden and click on not blog, instead of design it pops in again, instead of slides in. How can I work around this?

Comment: [It seems to be working fine.](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvml40v863)

Comment: can you show us the component?

Comment: Added some more code and new code. It looks like from /code clicking on code it slides in but if I am not at the matching URL it just pops in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have called SideBar component unnecessarily more than one time. Now it is only loaded once and animation works.